# Javascript DOM identifying nodes by user type?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I have a tbody with some tr children nodes, how can I give each tr a user specified value that can be used to identify it?

For example I want to do something like:

```
mytr1 = mytbody.createElement('tr');
mytr2 = mytbody.createElement('tr');

mytr1.userident = 'firstname';
mytr2.userident = 'lastname';

tbody.appendChild(mytr1);
tbody.appendChild(mytr2);
```

Then have the ability for one child to access its sibling like:

```
mystr1.parentNode.getByUserident('lastname')
```

I don't want to use id's because the objects are dynamically created and destroyed, and names are not valid for tr elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use datasets.
It's HTML5, but it's fairly supported. [Datasets support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset)

Here's how to use them :

```
mytr1 = mytbody.createElement('tr');
mytr2 = mytbody.createElement('tr');

mytr1.dataset.userident = 'firstname';
mytr2.dataset.userident = 'lastname';

tbody.appendChild(mytr1);
tbody.appendChild(mytr2);
```

For accessing them, 
implying you're using event binding and handling :

```
var userident = evt.target.dataset.userident;
```

**EDIT**

Actually it's supported by all browsers right now.
The only partially supported part is the access to the *.dataset* property.
Simply use *.getAttribute('data-userident')* and *.setAttribute('data-userident','firstname')* on your elements.

Comment: Sweet! I knew there must have been something like this, because its so useful. I just couldn't figure out what to search for.